# What does a TARDIS start as?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, gallifrey, chameleon-circuit

The Doctor's TARDIS is always its iconic blue police box - but this is not standard; it is due to its chameleon circuit (the thing that is meant to change its appearance to camouflage into its surroundings) being broken. But normally a TARDIS would change to camouflage.

**My question is what would a TARDIS look like when it is first grown on Gallifrey?**

Answer (score 20):

We see the Doctor stealing the TARDIS in "*The Name of The Doctor*".

It basically looks like a big white (silver?) tube with a sliding door.

And again in "*Hell Bent."*

[image]

Comment: Dammit, I was just collecting that screenshot from iPlayer.

Comment: @OrangeDog - If only you could go back in time and answer it faster :-)

Comment: [If you want it](https://i.imgur.com/v55pgpK.png)

Comment: Interesting...  I thought we see that row of TARDISs on another occasion... the clipped scene is from time-splintered Clara, but I thought we see the same row when "Capaldi" Doctor steals the TARDIS in "Hell Bent".

Comment: I think there are some "plain" TARDISes shown in Day of the Doctor too during the war. For classic series I would check The Deadly Assassin.

Comment: For the classic series possibly also in "The War Games".

Comment: This is, of course, just the simplest representational form for the projection of a convenient access manifold between the hyperdimensional interior and normal 4-dimensional spacetime. :) I wonder if there's a 'works' entrance to get big stuff in and out. Or maybe the concept of discrete entrances is irrelevant and it just sizes the projection according to need.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru [Flatline](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Flatline_(TV_story)) would seem to agree with the latter.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru - When you've got time travel you can just move forward to a point when the TARDIS is completed and materialise it around any large items that won't fit through the door.

Comment: Are we sure that this is its "natural" look, rather than its camouflage matching the brutalist/neo-industrial design of the rest of the room?

Comment: @Sneftel - This is what a TARDIS would look like if it was made in Birmingham.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't, @Valorum? ;)

Comment: It’s perhaps telling that these TARDISes look quite similar to the SIDRATs seen in The War Games, which don’t have chameleon circuits. The novelisation of Shada gives them as a predecessor of the TARDIS, which might also be evidence that this is indeed what a default TARDIS looks like. But I suspect the “growing” is only the interior dimension, and they don’t really have a “true” exterior, just a default.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie - The sidrats are featureless grey (or green) boxes, not tubes; https://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?topic=2438.0

Comment: @Valorum yes, I know; it think that’s quite similar to a featureless grey (or silver) tube, though. Not identical certainly, but it gives an idea of what a TARDIS without a chameleon circuit might look like.